# Composition of Multivariable function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to compose functions of `xleft`, maybe like `xleft[xleft[f]]` or even higher order. And here is my function:

```
xleft := Function [{f}, D[f[x, y, z], x] - y*D[f[x, y, z], z]/2]
```

But I couldn't make it work  like  `xleft[xleft[f]]` since I guess there are problems of mapping different dimensions. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to be consistent about using only **expressions** as arguments to the operator, not function heads. The reason is that the operator as you define it returns an expression and not a function. That's why you then cannot apply the operator twice. But by working only with expressions, this problem is avoided:

```
xleft = Function[f, D[f, x] - y  D[f, z]/2];

xleft[f[x, y, z]]
```

> $f^{(1,0,0)}(x,y,z)-\frac{1}{2} y
>    f^{(0,0,1)}(x,y,z)$

```
xleft[xleft[f[x, y, z]]]
```

> $-\frac{1}{2} y
>    f^{(1,0,1)}(x,y,z)-\frac{1}{2} y
>    \left(f^{(1,0,1)}(x,y,z)-\frac{1
>    }{2} y
>    f^{(0,0,2)}(x,y,z)\right)+f^{(2,
>    0,0)}(x,y,z)$

Now you can apply the operator as many times as you like. The only difference in the application is that the argument `f` has to be replaced by `f[x,y,z]`.

**Alternatively** (but I'd prefer the first approach), you could also work only with functions and **not** with expressions:

```
Clear[xleft];
xleft = Function[f, 
   Function[{x, y, z}, D[f[x, y, z], x] - y D[f[x, y, z], z]/2]];

xleft[xleft[f]][x, y, z]
```

> $-\frac{1}{2} y
>    f^{(1,0,1)}(x,y,z)-\frac{1}{2} y
>    \left(f^{(1,0,1)}(x,y,z)-\frac{1
>    }{2} y
>    f^{(0,0,2)}(x,y,z)\right)+f^{(2,
>    0,0)}(x,y,z)$

Here, the operator returns a function but then you have to evaluate the result by giving it back the arguments at the end.